# In codelgniter model file two function data how to call in one javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

my first function in model file

```
 function sales_orders(){

    $sql="SELECT
        tu.user_id,
        tt.territory_id,
        tp.product_id,
        tpt.product_type,
        tb.brand_name,
        product_flavour
        FROM
tbl_product tp
    INNER JOIN
tbl_product_type tpt ON tpt.product_type_id = tp.product_type_id
    INNER JOIN
tbl_category tc ON tc.id_category = tp.category_id
    INNER JOIN
tbl_brand tb ON tb.id_brand = tc.brand_id
    INNER JOIN
tbl_product_flavour tpf ON tpf.product_flavour_id = tp.flavour_Id
    INNER JOIN
tbl_stock_history_manage tshm ON tshm.product_id = tp.product_id
      INNER JOIN
tbl_territory tt ON tt.territory_id = tshm.territory_id
        INNER JOIN
tbl_user tu ON tu.user_id = tshm.user_id
  where
  tshm.status = 1 ";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            foreach ($query->result() as $row){
                $sql2="SELECT
                        SUM(`dealer_price`) AS dealer_price
                        FROM 
                        `tbl_product_has_price` 
                        WHERE `product_id` = $row->product_id
                      ";//price(rd)

                    $query2= $this->db->query($sql2);
                    $dealer_price =$query2->result();

                $sql3="SELECT SUM(`price`) as price 
                       from
                       `tbl_purchase_order_has_details`
                      WHERE
                       `product_id` = $row->product_id 

                        ";  //price(pur)      

                    $query3 = $this->db->query($sql3);
                    $price =$query3->result();

                $sql4="SELECT
                         SUM(`stock_plus`) as totalPurchase
                        FROM 
                          `tbl_stock_history_manage`
                        WHERE 
                          `stock_type` = 'PURCHASE'
                        AND  
                       product_id = $row->product_id 
                        AND territory_id = $row->territory_id
                         AND user_id = $row->user_id"; //total purchase       

                    $query4 = $this->db->query($sql4);
                    $toatal_purchase =$query4->result();    

                     $sql5="SELECT 
                             SUM(`stock_plus`) AS freeIssueseIn
                            FROM 
                              `tbl_stock_history_manage`
                    WHERE 
                     `stock_type` = 'PURCHASE_FREE' 
                    AND  
                       product_id = $row->product_id 
                             AND territory_id = $row->territory_id
                         AND user_id = $row->user_id"; //free issuse in      

                    $query5= $this->db->query($sql5);
                    $free_issuese_in =$query5->result(); 


                    $sql6="SELECT
                        SUM(`stock_plus`+`mobile_stock_plus`) AS stocktrain 
                    FROM 
                      `tbl_stock_history_manage`
                    WHERE 
                         `stock_type` = 'STOCK ADJESMENT PLUSE'
                     AND
                       product_id = $row->product_id 
                            AND territory_id = $row->territory_id
                         AND user_id = $row->user_id"; //stock_tra_in      

                    $query6= $this->db->query($sql6);
                    $stock_tra_in =$query6->result(); 

                      $sql7="SELECT
                           SUM(`stock_plus`-`stock_minus`)+sum(`mobile_stock_plus`-`mobile_stock_minus`) AS openStock
                        FROM 
                             `tbl_stock_history_manage` WHERE

                       product_id = $row->product_id 
                         AND territory_id = $row->territory_id
                         AND user_id = $row->user_id "; //open stock      

                    $query7= $this->db->query($sql7);
                    $openStock =$query7->result();


                    $sql8="SELECT
                        SUM(`stock_plus`) totalsales
                    FROM
                      `tbl_stock_history_manage` 
                    WHERE
                        `stock_type` = 'SALES'
                         AND
                       product_id = $row->product_id 
                          AND territory_id = $row->territory_id
                         AND user_id = $row->user_id"; //totalSales      

                    $query8 = $this->db->query($sql8);
                  $totalSales =$query8->result();

                    $sql9="SELECT
                SUM(`stock_minus`+`mobile_stock_minus`) AS stockTraOut 
                FROM 
               `tbl_stock_history_manage`
                WHERE
               `stock_type` = 'STOCK ADJESMENT PLUSE' AND
                       product_id = $row->product_id  AND
                             territory_id = $row->territory_id
                         AND user_id = $row->user_id"; //stockTraOut     

                    $query9= $this->db->query($sql9);
                  $stockTraOut =$query9->result();

                   $sql10="SELECT
                    SUM(stock_minus) freeIssuesOut
                FROM 
                 `tbl_stock_history_manage` 
                WHERE 
                 `stock_type` = 'FREE' 
                 AND
                       product_id = $row->product_id  AND territory_id = $row->territory_id
                         AND user_id = $row->user_id"; //freeIssueseOut     

                    $query10= $this->db->query($sql10);
                  $freeIssuesOut =$query10->result();




                    $return_array[] = array(
                                            'brand_name'=>$row->brand_name,
                                            'product_type'=>$row->product_type,
                                            'product_flavour'=>$row->product_flavour,
                                            'dealer_price'=>$dealer_price,
                                            'price'=>$price ,
                                            'openStock'=>$openStock,
                                            'total_purchase'=>$toatal_purchase,
                                            'free_issuese_in'=>$free_issuese_in,   
                                            'stock_tra_in'=>$stock_tra_in,
                                            'tot'=> number_format(count($openStock) > 0 ? $openStock[0]->openStock:0,2)+($toatal_purchase[0]->totalPurchase)+($free_issuese_in[0]->freeIssueseIn)+($stock_tra_in[0]->stocktrain),//total
                                            'totalsales'=>$totalSales,
                                            'stockTraOut'=>$stockTraOut,
                                            'freeIssuesOut'=>$freeIssuesOut,
                                            'clossing_blnc'=>  number_format(count($stockTraOut)> 0 ? $stockTraOut[0]->stockTraOut :0,2)+( $freeIssuesOut[0]->freeIssuesOut)+($totalSales[0]->totalsales)-(number_format(count($openStock) > 0 ? $openStock[0]->openStock:0,2)+($toatal_purchase[0]->totalPurchase)+($free_issuese_in[0]->freeIssueseIn)+($stock_tra_in[0]->stocktrain))//closing balance
                                            );

            }

    return $return_array;                  


}
```

my second function

```
   function totalfooter(){
   $sql11="SELECT 
                SUM(`stock_plus`) AS totalPur 
                FROM 
                 `tbl_stock_history_manage` 
                WHERE `stock_type` = 'PURCHASE' AND territory_id=$row-   >territory_id AND user_id=$row->user_id";
                    $query1= $this->db->query($sql11);
                    foreach ($query1->result() as $row){
                         $return_array1[] = array(
                             'totalPur'=>$row->totalPur ,

                         ); 

                    }
  return $return_array1;
```

}

i want to get those data pass in to one javascript function. whether i don't know is it possible. because i try to get in same function.but it not possible. because that second function data i want to print in footer. in separate id i pass for print that data.

```
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="6" style="text-align: right;">Total</td>
  <td style="text-align: right;"><label  id="sl_amount"></label>  </tr>   </tfoot>
```

my javaScript like this

```
 function sales_orders(){


$j('#order_body').empty();

$j.ajax({
  url : 'sales_orders',
  method : 'post',
  data :{      
  },
  success: function (data){
      alert(data);
      var order = JSON.parse(data);
      var order_detail = [];
        $j('#lbl_rescount').text.length;
        $j('#rows_token').val.length;
     // var or_de =[];
      if (order!== 0) {
      for( var x=0; x<order.length;x++){
          order_detail.push(
                  '<tr>'
          +'<td>'+ order[x].brand_name + '</td>'
          +'<td>'+ order[x].product_type + '</td>'
          +'<td>'+ order[x].product_flavour +'</td>'
          +'<td>' + order[x].dealer_price[0].dealer_price +'</td>'
          +'<td>' + order[x].price[0].price+'</td>'
          +'<td>' + order[x].openStock[0].openStock +'</td>'
          +'<td>' + order[x].total_purchase[0].totalPurchase+'</td>'
          +'<td>'+ order[x].free_issuese_in[0].freeIssueseIn + '</td>'
          +'<td>'+ order[x].stock_tra_in[0].stocktrain + '</td>'
          +'<td>' + order[x].tot+'</td>'
          +'<td>' + order[x].totalsales[0].totalsales+'</td>' 
          +'<td>'+ order[x].stockTraOut[0].stockTraOut + '</td>'
          +'<td>'+ order[x].freeIssuesOut[0].freeIssuesOut + '</td>'
          +'<td>'+ order[x].clossing_blnc + '</td>'
          +'</tr>'
                  );
      }
      }else
           sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went wrong! No records found..", "error");
            $j('#lbl_rescount').text('0');
     $j('#order_body').html(order_detail);
  }

});}
```

in here my datapass in json array object array objrct....etc... so any how i want to print total in footer ......if there any more suggestion please tell me.

Comment: You can only call one URL per AJAX request.  You could create a new method in your controller that calls both model methods and prepares the data as needed, then return it to the AJAX call.

Comment: in my model file i try to pass  footer data also in same function. assign  variable in  $total_pur=""; and call anothe sub array and return data into same javascript function. $j('#sl_amount').text(order['totals_td'][0].tot_purchase);                                                              $total_pur                                                                             += $tot_purchase->totalPur;
        
        $purchase['totals_td'][]=array(
            'tot_purchase' => number_format($total_pur , 2)
    );     but its not print data

Comment: can you try with `return json_encode($return_array);` in your    `sales_orders` function.

Comment: in controller i pass json encoder      public  function sales_orders() {echo json_encode($this->monthly_stock_sts_model1->sales_orders());}

Comment: First, you can do more than one Ajax request at a time. Another idea is, the first URL function you hit, you can do a CURL post to the next function, then on success, update the HTML sections. You can do multiple Ajax requests at once

Comment: i'll try.. how to give url separating  / or